# Admin approval for editing user profile

Tags: users, advanced-custom-fields

I was looking for a plugin but to no avail. Anyway, I'm building a custom Wordpress theme using ACF Pro (which works perfectly) and have added a lot of different custom fields for each user (like price, location, skills, etc.)

What I'd like to do is control the prices or at least get an email as soon as the user changes one of the ACF fields (like price or location) so I can compare the original and new value. Let's say the user has a price of 20€/hour - if he changes that value to e.g. 30€, I'd like to get an email or have the ability to approve these changes. The user profile shouldn't be deactivated in the meantime though, I'd just like to approve these changes before they go live.

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: This seems very specific to plugin and is better aimed at its developers/support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update_option()` function has a filter for that:

```
$value = apply_filters( "pre_update_option_{$option}", $new_value, $old_value );
```

Immediately after that filter, there's another filter that you do **not** want to use.

```
$value = apply_filters( 'pre_update_option', $value, $option, $old_value );
```

(If you would use that, you will have to check the option name *inside* the callback, which adds unnecessary overhead.

What you need to do then, to react on a specific option changing contents by [sending a mail via `wp_mail()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_mail/), is to attach a callback to that filter. Read the `@TODO` and fill in the missing bits:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#16621) Send mail after Option Value changed */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', '166221reactMail' );
function 166221reactMail()
{
    // @TODO Add you option names (valid triggers) here:
    $valid = [
        'your',
        'option',
        'names',
        'here',
    ];

    // Attach each filter: Precise targetting option names
    foreach ( $valid as $name )
    {
        add_filter( "pre_update_option_{$name}", function( $new, $old )
        {
            # @TODO Adjust check/validity of mail trigger here
            if ( $new !== $old )
            {
                # @TODO uncomment the following line - see note below
                // add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', '166221reactMailFrom' );

                # @TODO Adjust values for wp_mail()
                wp_mail(
                    'To@example.com',
                    sprintf( 'Change notification from %s', get_option( 'blogname' ) ),
                    sprintf( 'Value changed from %s to %s', $old, $new )
                );
            }

            return $new;
        }
    }
}
```

To make it easier to add creating highly specific mail inbox rules easier, you might want to add the following as well:

```
// @TODO Change "from" Name to make creating inbox rules easier
function 166221reactMailFrom( $from )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return "foo@bar.com";
}
```

#### Edit

Just realized that I wrote an answer on the *option* filters, which doesn't make any sense on *post meta* filters. You will have to exchange the filter names with those from [`update_metadata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/update_metadata/), which is triggered by the following from `update_post_meta()` where the `$meta_type` is `post`. There are two filters or actions to use:

```
do_action( "update_{$meta_type}_meta", $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value );
```

or, if you know that you use a `post` posttype:

```
do_action( 'update_postmeta', $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
```

and if you want to trigger *after* the value has updated:

```
do_action( "updated_{$meta_type}_meta", $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value );
```

and specifically for the `post` post type:

```
do_action( 'updated_postmeta', $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
```

Comment: Thx kaiser, you rock! I didn't try this out yet, but I'm not sure if this applies to users? I don't work with posts here, just users, so I'd like to send an email as soon as a user updates his profile.

Comment: Well, that would be user meta data then. So you will have to replace the `$meta_type` with `user` (I guess here right now as I don't know it without looking at the source or a dump). Then just send the mail on that action.